# Data import Google Analytics - Applications

Tags: google-analytics

I manage the analytics for a College.

Is there any benefit to importing the .csv file of our student applications into Google Analytics?

It provides all personal details on course applied for/personal details?

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't import data that violates the [Google Analytics TOS](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) with regards to data that personally identifies an individual you can import all kinds of data and view that data joined in reports with your session data. You can see the [Data Import Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport) and [Data import Help Center](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589) content on how to go about it.